# Is it possible to show full posts in Grid layout?

Tags: wordpress, posts

Is it possible to show the full recent posts rather than excerpt on homepage in grid layout?

Comment: obviously you can.. you can have get_the_content() and can display full posts.. but i dont find any logic behind showing full posts in grid layout as it doesnt help your website speed SEO optimization and many other aspects that make a good decent website...

Comment: Great thank you, it worked for all posts page. But I am having requirement to show full 4 recent posts on homepage in grid layout. It will be on internal server so SEO will not be an issue so can you please suggests how can we achieve that?

Comment: To get that grid layout and get those recent posts in grid you can always use WP Query where you can have 'order'=>'DESC' parameter in query https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always add your html into the below code

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   =>'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'order'           =>'DESC'
        );

     $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
     if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
            $the_query->the_post();
      ?>
      <div class="gridlayout">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
      </div>

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hey sagar, thank you for the code, I tried it in my custom page template but it shows me an error "Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on null in" Can you please advise me why I am getting this error?

Comment: try it again i didnt check that in my code so there was a problem

Comment: Hey can we create a "short code" for this function, actually i want to use it on any page or post.

Comment: yes you can always use shortcode anywhere in wordpress and please mark it as correct

Comment: Hey sagar, Can you please advise me how to use this as a shortcode actually I did create a function and used it as shortcode its working but the contnent after that is floating(appending) with that, I tried to clear the grid layout float but not working can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `the_content()` or  `echo get_the_content()` instead `the_excerpt()` or echo `get_the_excerpt()` respectively .
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Souvik... But is it possible to in grid layout?